# fscanf function not working

Tags: scanf, formatted-input

I'm currently writing a program that reads numbers from sets of 2 numbers from a text file and prints them out. I'd like to use the numbers to determine a GCD later, but I have to be able to scan them from the file first. The text file looks like this:

```
24      72
25      50
31      89
...
```

Tab is pressed between each number in the first row and each number in the second.

I've come up with this so far (commented out section is to be used for determining the GCD):

```
/*
File name: euclid.cpp
This program find the largest common multiple of two numbers using the Euclid  method.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *input;
    long num1=0, num2=0, orinum2=0, rem=0, gcd=0;
    int i=0, size=0;
    char temp;

    input=fopen("Euclid.txt", "r"); 

    while((temp=getc(input))!=EOF)
    {
        if(temp=='\n') size++;
    }
    size++;

    while(i<size)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%d\t%d%[^\n]", &num1, &num2);
        printf("%d\t%d\n", num1, num2);
        orinum2=num2;
/*      while (true)
        {
            rem=num1%num2;
            if (rem==0)
            {
                gcd=num2; break;
            }
            else
            {
                num1=num2;
                num2=rem;
            }
        }
        printf("The GCD of %d and %d is %d.\n", num1, orinum2, gcd);
*/      i++;
    }

    fclose(input);

}
```

Every single webpage and resource I have checked dictates that this should work, but for some reason it just isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**fscanf**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) will "return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r"); ;
    int num1, num2;

    while(fscanf(input, "%d %d", &num1, &num2) > 0)
        printf("%d\t%d\n", num1, num2);

    fclose(input);
}
```

The pattern ("%d %d") will match and assign two integers, separated by any number of [**whitespace characters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Whitespace characters include your tab (\t), and newline (\n).

Comment: Could you clarify your 3rd point?  AS for point 2, the input does not actually have the characters "/" and "t", and i changed my formatting in the original post to accurately depict the text file. It seems stackoverflow messes up my formatting if its not done in a code segment.

Comment: So how would you change the formatting so that it reads the info until it encounters a new line? [^\n] is the way that most people on the internet seem to reccommend.

Comment: Point three was about regular expressions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). [^\n] means (Anything except newline) in regexp. The fscanf pattern is NOT a regexp, so you can not use that there.